# Grid rows - fill all available space

Tags: wpf

I would like to put two controls in WPF in a Grid - GridView and ScheduleView one above the other with GridSplitter like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadScheduleView Grid.Row="0" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="4"/>
    <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that there are three modes:
 - only GridView is shown
 - only ScheduleView is shown
 - GridView and ScheduleView are shown
In each case I want the visible control(s) to fill all available space. In case the two are shown I want them to share the space between them and GridSplitter should be able to resize that space.

How can I accomplish this without explicitly setting heights while changing display modes?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like a [MathConverter](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/) to explicitly set your Grid's heights based on some triggers

For example, if both Grids are visible, set their height to to be `((GridHeight - 4) / 2)`, while if only one grid is visible then set it to the Grid's full height since neither the GridSplitter nor the other Grid are visible.

Here's an example. I left out the visibility triggers since I'm assuming you already know how to implement them.

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadScheduleView x:Name="MyGridView" Grid.Row="0">
        <telerik:RadScheduleView.Style>
           <Style TargetType="telerik:RadScheduleView">
              <Setter Property="Height" 
                      Value="{Binding ElementName=ParentGrid, 
                                      Path=ActualHeight,
                                      Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
                                      ConverterParameter=((@VALUE-4)/2)}"/>
                 <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyScheduleView, Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
                      <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ElementName=ParentGrid, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
       </telerik:RadScheduleView.Style>
    </telerik:RadScheduleView>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="4"/>

    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="MyScheduleView" Grid.Row="2"
        <telerik:RadScheduleView.Style>
           <Style TargetType="telerik:RadScheduleView">
              <Setter Property="Height" 
                      Value="{Binding ElementName=ParentGrid, 
                                      Path=ActualHeight,
                                      Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
                                      ConverterParameter=((@VALUE-4)/2)}" />
                 <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyGridView, Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
                      <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ElementName=ParentGrid, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
       </telerik:RadScheduleView.Style>
    </telerik:RadScheduleView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the height of two rows as `*` which means it will fill all the available space.
And bind the GridSplitter with the visibility of two columns using `Triggers` or `Converter` whichever you feel comfortable with. With trigger this would work-

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadScheduleView Grid.Row="0" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
       <GridSplitter.Style>
           <Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                 <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn1, Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn2, Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
       </GridSplitter.Style>
    </GridSplitter>
    <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

I am assuming that Visibility for your GridView's are already in place (the logic of how to play with the visibility). Make sure you set the Visibility to `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden` for your GridViews.

Comment: I set them to Collapsed and grid rows are not resized. I'll try to set VerticalAlignment to Stretch.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. I was trying DataTriggers for setting Height of grid rows, but no effect so far..